# Can USB-C charger from laptop be used to charge USB-C Samsung phone?

Tags: charging

I have a Samsung S8 phone, which has USB-C charging connector. I lost the original charger for my phone, but I have the original USB-C charger for my Huawei Matebook X Pro laptop. **Is it possible to use this charger to charge the phone? Is the USB-C standard itself a guarantee that all the relevant characteristics will be equivalent?**

Here is the electric info from the mobile phone charger (which has USB-A female output connector, and there was USB-A to USB-C cable which I lost):

```
OUTPUT: 5.0V = 2.0A, 10.0W
        9.0V = 1.67A, 15.0W
```

Here is the electric info from the laptop charger (which has USB-C female output connector):

```
OUTPUT: 5.0V = 2.0A, 10.0W
        9.0V = **2.0A**, **18.0W**
       12.0V = 2.0A, 24.0W
       15.0V = 3.0A, 45.0W
       20.0V = 3.25A, 65.0W
```

(There is a difference in ampere and wattage for the 9.0V, is that a problem or is it that the device will just take what it needs?)

Comment: Is the wattage really 18.0W? Wattage is Voltage x Ampere, so having the same V and A shouldn't produce a different W.

Comment: @AndrewT. sorry, there is a difference in amperes too! I have edited the post. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia Samsung S8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S8#Batteries) uses Qualcomm Quick Charge 2.0 for the higher voltage levels. When using a standard USB-C charger with the S8 the maximum is 5V * 2.5A = 12.5 Watt.

Most likely the laptop USB-C charger only supports USB Power Delivery and thus it will charge at maximum with 12.5 Watt.

Comment: ... so, the conclusion is? :-)

Comment: @Tomas The conclusion is what I wrote in the last sentence. Expect to get 12.5 Watt @ 5V.

Comment: so, what is the answer to my question?

Comment: @Thomas I am sorry but the answer is clear and I have already written it: your phone does not support USB power delivery with more than 5Volt so it will not load with 9V because it only supports proprietary Qualcomm Quick Charge 2.0.